# Where is value coming from in formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have been sent an Excel sheet and I am trying to workout how one of the formulas works. It has an if statement in it and the value if true looks to be some sort of variable that references a formula somewhere else. How can I find out where this is? Its the value the says citr with a little tag by it.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That icon represents a defined name.  You can use [the Name Manager to look them up](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-2d9abce7-42cf-4a21-a6b4-f02786f690b7#bmmanage_names_by_using_the_name_manage):

> To open the **Name Manager** dialog box, on the **Formulas** tab, in the
>   **Defined Names** group, click **Name Manager**.

Answer (score 2):

Some one has assigned a **Name** to either a cell or a formula.  Go to the *Formulas* tab and touch the *Name Manager* button to see.